# Arduino Uno and Leonardo SPI clock can't be measured

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-leonardo, spi

I want to measure the SPI clock (pin 13) using the Arduino example code for the SPI library (very simple example). Basically independent from the `loop` function, the clock should be fired continuously.

I deployed the Arduino SPI example code on the board and measured pin 13 on an oscilloscope, but nothing was found, always zero volt.

Comment: Note: In contrast to Arduino Uno, on the Arduino Leonardo the SPI clock (SCK) is ***not*** connected to pin 13 (see *[SPI library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPI)*, sub section *"Connections"*)

Comment: On Arduino Leonardo the SPI signals are only available on the six-pin ICSP header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please note the SPI clock will only be active while it is shifting data. So simply put the spi.transfer in a hard loop

```
#include <SPI.h>

void setup() {
  SPI.begin();
  while (1) {
    SPI.transfer(0x00);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thnaks alot mpflaga for your help. i will test it today and i hope it will work..thanks alot really !!